# Get json dict value

Tags: python

I want to get json output via below method for some reason, this is my cut short code:

```
json_load = json.loads(json_file)
output = json.dumps({str(key): str(value) for key, value in json_load.items()})
sys.stdout.write(output)
```

Comment: Am I mistaken, or is your expected output exactly the same as the input, only with condensed whitespace?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to have a more descriptive title. Getting the value from a dict is as simple as `dict[key]`, and that's not really what you're asking.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, yes, expected output exactly the same as the input.

Comment: The last edit has removed the question and made it impossible to answer. From your comments below it seems you're experiencing an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323). If your goal is to pass a JSON file to terraform, your original file should work directly. There must be some other problem tangential to what you were describing. Until you can provide reproducible error conditions, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating the output. This works:

```
output = json.dumps(json_load)
```

Comment: I understand, and this is not what I want. Because I want to pass the output to `terraform external source`,  and it will have this err: `Error: command "python3" produced invalid JSON: unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: @Lawrence That's a separate issue. Is it because you're not writing a trailing newline to `sys.stdout`?

Comment: What do you mean by trailing newline?

Comment: @Lawrence `sys.stdout.write('\n')` Normally in Unix-based environments, files have a trailing newline, so it'd make sense if Terraform required one, though I've never used it myself.

Comment: Refer to my output, {"test_db": `"`{'name': 'test_db', 'all': False, 'state': 'open', 'Table': {'tbl_1': {'name': 'tbl_1', 'state': 'normal', 'all': True}}}}`"`}, I just want to know how to output without `"`?

Comment: @Lawrence What do you mean? That's different from the expected output you wrote in the question. Have you actually tried my code? Because it does produce the expected output you wrote in the question. And it's valid JSON. If Terraform has a problem, there's something else going on. Like for example, maybe you're writing something to stdout **before** the `write(output)`.